# How to access html element name in array format inside an angularjs expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, html, devise

I am using ruby on rails devise for authentication. I need to validate the login form on client side. Devise uses user[email] as name attribute value. How do I use the same name in angularjs ng-show expression ?

```
<form ng-app="" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="user[email]" ng-model="user" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.user[email].$error.required">Username is required</span>
</form>
```

user[email] does not work in angularjs ng-show expression.

Answer (score 0):

Angular not access to ruby on rails variable.

Comment: Its not a ror variable. It is a html element name in array notation that needs to be accessed from angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way, this is my example using devise gem and angular 1.3.14

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {name: "profileForm", novalidate: false}) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, autofocus: true, "ng-model"=>"profile.firstname", required: true %>


    <div ng-messages="profileForm['user[firstname]'].$error" class="errors">
      <span ng-message="required">Required!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

NOTE: You will need to add angular-messages.js and the module in your app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-messages.js"></script>
  .....
```

in your app.js

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngMessages"]);

}());
```